# Weird but working var declaration syntax

Tags: javascript

I use this syntax often but I don't understand why it simply works.

```
var a = 1, b = a + 1;
console.log(b); // 2
```

In the event you're declaring a var, after splitting them on a comma, the `b` already sees `a` as evaluated? Why is that?

Comment: When i first saw this i thought its just like scheme's `let*`. In scheme, the example would be `(let* ((a 1) (b (+ a 1))) b)` which expands to `(let ((a 1)) (let ((b (+ a 1))) b))`. Just like [Tigraine's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8533977/388787) but with more nesting.

Comment: I don't see that as weird: to me it seems logical that it should just evaluate each item in turn, left to right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been [defined](http://es5.github.com/x12.html#x12.2) as such.

First, the definition of the essential terms:

> *VariableStatement* :
>
> `var` *VariableDeclarationList* `;`

and:

> *VariableDeclarationList* :
>
> *VariableDeclaration*
>
> *VariableDeclarationList* , *VariableDeclaration*

The actual definition which applies to your question is this one:

> The production *VariableDeclarationList* : *VariableDeclarationList* , *VariableDeclaration* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Evaluate *VariableDeclarationList*.
> 2. Evaluate *VariableDeclaration*.

So at the time #2 is executed, #1 has been evaluated already and you can use any effect of it in #2.

Comment: @nnnnnn: That's what it comes down to; it is evaluated in the same order the source code is, so left to right and top to bottom.

Answer (score 3):

That's due to how variables are declared in JavaScript. Variable declaration in Javascript happens in two steps. First, the all the variables declared in the current scope are initialized and given the value undefined and after all the variables are declared this way, they are then given their actual value. So your code:

```
var a = 1, b = a + 1;
```

is translated to:

```
var a = undefined;
var b = undefined;
a = 1;
b = a + 1;
```

This is called hoisting. As all the variables you declare are hoisted at the top of the scope. This allows you to do weird things like:

```
var a = b;  // b = undefined
var b = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply because a gets initialized before b. This process goes from the left to the right.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit counter-intuitive but just think of it as equal to this:

```
var a = 1;
var b = a + 1;
```

Unlike other languages like Python where multiple assignments operate on the previous values (making swaps easier)